# How can I new a Template-Specialization Class object?

Tags: c++, templates

I write a Template-Specialization Class like this:

```
template <> class MEField<SField> {....};
```

I want to know how to make a instantiation of this class? I see some code writing like this: `MEField<> obj`? Is that right?

I know under function-specialization case, I can make a instantiation as normal because the compiler can judge the special type of parameters. But as for class, can you tell me the truly format?

Answer (score 3):

You do it normally like other templates, `MEField<SField> obj;`. User of the class is not bothered whether you have specialized the template or not, it is up to the compiler to decide which instantiation of the template to use.

Comment: @xunzhang: You can do that with default template arguments: `template <typename T = SField> class MEField;`

Comment: @xunzhang Not sure if that is what you have seen, but, apart from what Jesse said (which is also true), you can have `MEField<> obj` if `MEField` was declared with a parameter pack: `MEField<typename... Args>`. That works only in C++11, and means: Instantiate the template using _the empty pack_.

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
template <> class MEField<SField> {....};
```

What you did is explicit specialization. As [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5ca42y.aspx) says,

> The compiler generates code for a template class or function when the class or function is instantiated.

It further states,

> If a template is explicitly instantiated or specialized once, it cannot be explicitly instantiated or specialized a second time in the same program for the same set of template arguments. Further specializations with different template arguments are allowed.

So the standard way is to write like this.

```
MEField<SField> obj;
```

However, As Jesse Good said, you can use default template arguments that will not require you to specify the type while instantiation as it uses the default type you specified.

Refer the code below (Tested code)

```
class SField
{
public:
    int m_var;
    SField():m_var(0){}
};

template<typename T = SField> // Default template argument.
class MEField
{
public:
   T m_var;
};

template <>
class MEField<SField> // Explicit specialization
{
public:
   SField sField;
   void print(){ cout << sField.m_var; }
};

int main()
{
    MEField<> obj;
    obj.print();
}
```

Also refer: [Default Arguments for Class Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bys786s7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)